# How to choose a random ID from a table and use it for populate random data to another table?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert random data to do a stress test for my application, following this [guideline](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5148/populate-large-tables-with-random-data-for-sql-server-performance-testing/).

I've some foreign key on some columns, and I want to insert some random data for those too.

Let say table `Clinics` have 5 records, with ID "3,7,90,98,102"; for each insert on `Activities` I'd like to pick one of those 5 IDs. Tried with:

```
Declare @clinicId int

Declare @counter int
Set @counter = 11

While @counter < 12
Begin 
    @clinicId = SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Clinics ORDER BY NEWID()

   Insert Into Activities values (@clinicId, 100, 10, 90, 2, 65, 1)

   Set @counter = @counter + 1
End
```

But it says `Syntax error in proximity of @clinicId`. Any clues?

Comment: Someone with 17.5k rep should know that "It doesn't work" is a useless statement. What error did you come across? Did you get a syntax error? Is it inserting, but the data is wrong?

Comment: Rejected to OP for clarification of the error

Comment: added the error. Sorry it was in different language, I've made my own translation!

Comment: `set @clinicId = (SELECT TOP 1 clinic_id from ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be fixed this way:

```
set @clinicId = (SELECT TOP 1 clinic_id from ...)
```

Or you can get rid of loop and variables by set-based solution (supposed to replace all script given):

```
declare @cnt int = 12

Insert Into dbo.Activities (...)
SELECT
  c.clinicID, 100, 10, 90, 2, 65, 1
FROM 
(
   SELECT TOP (@cnt) 1 dummy
   from master.dbo.spt_values
) v
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) c.clinicID
  FROM dbo.Clinics c
  ORDER BY NEWID()
) c
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: your `set @clinicId = (SELECT TOP 1 clinic_id from ...)` worked for me! Not sure about this code, but if you also insert that snippet, you got Accepted ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need `top (1)` prior to assignment :

```
SELECT TOP (1) @clinicId = ID 
FROM Clinics 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Note :

- You can assign only single column value to scalar variable.

If you want to assign all data, then you use table variable